# Criar uma lista com uma Model e um Int em C#

Tags: c#, winforms, lista

tenho a seguinte classe:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Dynamic;

namespace Model
{

    class PromocaoQtdeVendidaModel
    {
        private int idPromocaoQtdeVendida;
        private String descricao;
        private List<ProdutoModel> listaProdutos = new List<ProdutoModel>();                    
        private EmpresaModel empresa = new EmpresaModel();
        private DateTime dataCadastro;
        private DateTime dataInicio;
        private DateTime dataFim;
        private int quantidadeMix;

        public DateTime DataFim
        {
            get { return dataFim; }
            set { dataFim = value; }
        }

        public DateTime DataInicio
        {
            get { return dataInicio; }
            set { dataInicio = value; }
        }

        public DateTime DataCadastro
        {
            get { return dataCadastro; }
            set { dataCadastro = value; }
        }

        public EmpresaModel Empresa
        {
            get { return empresa; }
            set { empresa = value; }
        }

        public int IdPromocaoQtdeVendida
        {
            get { return idPromocaoQtdeVendida; }
            set { idPromocaoQtdeVendida = value; }
        }

        public String Descricao
        {
            get { return descricao; }
            set { descricao = value; }
        }

        public List<ProdutoModel> ListaProdutos
        {
            get { return listaProdutos; }
            set { listaProdutos = value; }
        }        
    }
}
```

e preciso que a listaProduto tenha um INT quantidadeItem estou tentando fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
    private List<int> quantidadeIte = new List<int>();

    public List<ProdutoModel> ListaProdutos
    {
        get { return listaProdutos; }
        set { 
                listaProdutos.AddRange(quantidadeItem);
                listaProdutos = value; 
            }
    }
```

mas, está dando o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

não queria alterar minha model produto, pois, vou usar esse int apenas nessa model.

alguém sabe como poderia fazer?

Comment: Jovem, você pode [edit] sua pergunta e ser mais específico? O seu código não faz sentido, então nos explique qual o seu problema e como você acha que pode resolvê-lo, assim poderemos te mostrar como fazer em código.

Comment: Lilloh, recomendo que deia uma lida sobre o padrão ViewModel: http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2013/08/asp-net-mvc-view-model-pattern-quando-e-como-utilizar/

Comment: @ArturoTemplário vi o link que você me passou, acredito que isso atenda o que eu preciso. Eu tava achando que eu poderia fazer um get e um set dentro de uma model (Produto) pela model (Promoção) mas, pelo o que eu to pesquisado não é possível.

Comment: @LINQ eu não sei detalhar mais minha duvida. Mas, basicamente tenho uma MODEL PRODUTO (que te os atributos do produto) e preciso criar uma MODEL PROMOÇÃO dentro da promoção terá uma lista de produto porque eu preciso que dentro da lista de produto tenha uma int quantidade minima... melhorou?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve usar uma ViewModel, que é uma Model voltada para o que irá ser exibido na View. Em outras palavras, você pode criar uma Model, PromocaoQtdeVendidaViewModel, por exemplo, onde ela terá duas propriedades: a PromocaoQtdeVendidaModel e a quantidade de itens. Na sua View, você trabalhará com um IEnumerable PromocaoQtdeVendidaViewModel.

Exemplo:

```
 class PromocaoQtdeVendidaViewModel
{
    public int quantidadeIte {get; set;}

    public ProdutoModel Produto {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Eu queria eu esses quantidadeItem estivesse dentro da Model teria como?

Comment: Sim. A Model seria essa nova classe. Seu controller retornará a PromocaoQtdeVendidaViewModel ao invés da ProdutoModel, para sua View. No Controller, você irá criar uma lista de PromocaoQtdeVendidaViewModel, onde cada uma terá um objeto ProdutoModel e a quantidade de itens.